# ECS Task running, but I can't access in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

My task's status is RUNNING and I can see the image on EC2 instance with `docker ps`. But when I try to access the public IP and port the browser says that nothing was found. I've alredy set a security group rule to allow access to all TCP ports. What else can I do?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000

ENV PERSONAPI_ConnectionStrings__Database="[db connection string]"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY [".", "personApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "personApi/personApi.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "personApi/personApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "personApi/personApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "personApi.dll"]
```

Task ports:

[image: Task ports]

Docker on EC2 instance

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
8277d3be6a74        public.ecr.aws/z0o4m5x8/padrao:latest   "dotnet personApi.dll"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->5000/tcp   ecs-api-contato-2-api-contato-aeeefe81b1c8e7b75700
```

Comment: Please keep text in text and screenshots to a minimum.  Your dockerfil and docker ps  should be text.

Comment: Can you provide some additional information: 1. Does your VPC have an internet gateway attached to it? 2. What AMI is your ec2 instance using (it may have a firewall on it)? 3. Do you have your ECS task attached directly to a different security group than your instance?

Comment: @Patrick I studying AWS and ECS for the first time now. I'll try to get this info

Comment: @Patrick 1. I believe so. Because I can access the EC2 instance using SSH and I can run "sudo yum update". 2. I'm using Amazon Linux 2, I didn't configure a firewall. 3. I didn't configure a security group on my task. The security group is configured on EC2 instance

Comment: Thanks for checking that @LeandroSouza! Can you also check your ECS Task definition, and let me know what the "network mode" is for the task?

Comment: @Patrick The network mode is bridge. I set this because I'm following a class

Comment: Hm, that all seems like it should be set up correctly. I can see that the IP address is resolving properly publicly as well. Given you can SSH to the box, the most likely issue remains that one of your security groups is blocking ingress traffic to the port :-/. One option you could try would be to run a curl command directly from the ec2 instance that's hosting the docker image (`curl localhost:32772`) to see if you can hit the docker instance locally.

Comment: @Patrick I run the curl command but nothin returns. Is that correct?

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-116 ~]$ curl localhost:32771/swagger/index.html
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-116 ~]$`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237737/discussion-between-patrick-and-leandro-souza).

Comment: @Patrick I set a rule to allow inbound access to all tcp ports, from 0 to 65535. When I run this image on my PC I can access normally

Comment: @Patrick I figured out what was wrong! Check my answer here. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong. After some research I discovered that by default swagger only works in development mode, that's why I accessed when executed from Visual Studio but I couldn't access after publish.

So I changed this configuration and published again.